# Accepted answer give me just 10 instead of 15 points

Tags: support, reputation

I'm not sure if there is any change in SO rules or I might be missing something. But one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242241/getting-image-out-of-database-with-php-echo/15242274#15242274) got accepted today & I get +10 points for it instead of +15.

What is the cause of that ? How exactly 10 points are calculated here ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answer wasn't accepted today. If you hover on the green tick mark, it clearly states that the answer was accepted on Mar 6 at 8:44. The `+15` was awarded that day itself.

[image: Accept answer time]

You got an upvote on that answer today and thus the `+10` for it(as evident from your reputation page) which says *+10   2 hours ago    upvote  Getting image out of database with PHP echo*.

[image: Upvote reputation change today]

Comment: where is the up vote

Comment: @Bala - Centre click the vote counter. It is a -1/+1 situation. The answer had a downvote long back and got a upvote today which made the vote counter 0.

Comment: +1, I don't have that privilege

Comment: @Bala - No problem! :)

Comment: +1 but you're missing a red hand drawn circle around `upvote` in your second snapshot :P

Comment: @R.J user needs [1000 points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to view vote counts. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I know that :) just that I was unaware of Bala's rep on SO. :)

Comment: @mehow - I miss that too. But its okay I guess, cuz it has just one entry, though free hand circles(red ofcourse) make things prettier :P